# How to make OpenID login using omniauth-openid gem secure?

Tags: ruby, security, openid, omniauth

I am using the 'omniauth-openid' gem to implement OpenID login. In my OmniAuth callback method I do something like this (it's simplified but conveys the important details):

```
def google
  oauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  if @user = User.find_by_email(oauth.info.email)
    sign_in(@user) and redirect_to '/dashboard'
  end
end
```

This is effectively the same as what the OmniAuth documentation on GitHub shows you to do; and yet I feel that it's very insecure. All an attacker would have to do is manually change the info.email parameter in the callback URL, and they could log in as any other user.

Is this a fundamental flaw in OmniAuth? Or is there some way to confirm that the params passed to the OmniAuth callback method were genuinely sent by the OpenID provider, and not modified by a bad guy?

Comment: I don't know for a fact, but I'm pretty sure OmniAuth is doing a lot more behind the scenes. I think you're question is more about whether or not the OpenID protocol is secure.

Answer (score -1):

I think that's what "protect_from_forgery" is for. http://ruby.about.com/od/mr/g/protectforgery.htm

Comment: `protect_from_forgery` prevents people from faking the session ID, but I am talking about faking the "info.email" parameter. Besides, generally you have to turn off `protect_from_forgery` for your OpenID callback URLs, because Google, etc. don't pass a Rails session token back when authenticating with OpenID.